# dart, how do you read the content body of a http request?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, dart

I am playing with dart http server and I'm not sure how to read the actual content sent in the http request: "{'text':'some text data.'}"

```dart
import 'dart:io';


void main() {

  HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 3000).then((server){
    server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
      print("request made");
      request.response.write('''
        <html>
          <head>
          </head>
          <body>
            <pre>
              HELLO:
              request info:
                method: ${request.method}
                uri: ${request.uri}
                content length: ${request.contentLength}
                content : //HOW DO I GET THIS?
            </pre>
            <script>

              var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
              req.open("POST","/a_demonstration");
              req.send("{'text':'some text data.'}");

            </script>
          </body>
        </html>
      ''');
      request.response.close();
    });
  });

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to know how to read on the client that receives that response? Do you just want to know how to read or also how to process the conent?

Comment: no on the server how do I get the json string I post back, Iv updated the code example, I want to read the actual data posted back from the client on the server and incorporate it in to the response that the server sends back, so the last line of the pre tag should read `content: {'text':'some text data'}` in the second response from the server, Im aware it doesnt actually show up on the screen I just view it in the dev tools network tab

Comment: I guess it's my fault as Alexandre had no problem understanding your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use :

```dart
import 'dart:convert' show utf8;

Future<String> content = utf8.decodeStream(request);
```

Answer (score 7):

Alexandre Ardhuin gave the short and correct answer, for anyone wanting to see full code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert' show UTF8;

void main() {

  HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 3000).then((server){
    server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
      print("request made");
      if(request.contentLength == -1){
        _sendResponse(request, '');
      }else{
        UTF8.decodeStream(request).then((data)=>_sendResponse(request,data));
      }
    });
  });

}

_sendResponse(HttpRequest request, String requestData){
  request.response.write('''
      <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
      <pre>
      HELLO:
      request info:
      method: ${request.method}
      uri: ${request.uri}
      content length: ${request.contentLength}
      content: ${requestData}
      </pre>
      <script>

      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.open("POST","/a_demonstration");
      req.send("{'text':'some text data.'}");

      </script>
      </body>
      </html>
  ''');
  request.response.close();
}
```